# Human legs clip through pants

Tags: vertex-groups

Im making a avatar for vrchat and when I check pose mode the legs clip through the pants, and when I try to combine the vertex group with the body there is no apply button when I try to change the vertex data.[image]

Comment: Can you find the assign button in the triangle tab?

Comment: you could mask some parts of your leg mesh with the Mask modifier

Comment: I fixed the issue by changing the current blender with a older version and it seemed to work